# Equivalent to curl command in axios (nodejs) for file upload?

Tags: node.js, flask, curl, axios, request

I have the following command that works in uploading a .wav file

```
curl  http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload -F file=@./1653671203458audio.wav
```

the relevant code on the server side is the following, using Flask

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT':
        print(request.files)
        #print(request.args)
        #print(request.form)
        #print(request.files["onlyFile"])
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return "no file was sent"
        file = request.files['file']
        print(file.filename)
        if file.filename == '':
            return "No  selected file"
        #if file in allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
        return "File was uploaded successfully"
```

I've tried many things to try and have it uploaded the same way in nodejs without success, the follwing is the latest and it returns "no file was sent"

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require('form-data');

var fData = new FormData()
selectedFile = fs.readFileSync("./1653671203458audio.wav")

fData.append("1653671203458audio.wav", Buffer.from(selectedFile));
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload", {
  fData, 
  headers: fData.getHeaders()
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: you can use this too convert curl to any other languages https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [axios example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#axios)

so `file=@./1653671203458audio.wav` should be `fData.append("file", selectedFile);`
also, axios post arguments are wrong, `headers` are separated:

try this:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require('form-data');

var fData = new FormData()
selectedFile = fs.createReadStream("./1653671203458audio.wav")

fData.append("file", selectedFile);
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload",
  fData,
{
  headers: {
    ...fData.getHeaders(),
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: that worked! I also found another working one that I'll probably add later for anyone checking this later
Thanks